# Is having non-deterministic functions in fast refresh materialized views really forbidden?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

If I create a materialized view (fast refresh) which contains a `virtual column` and the column contains a function, It raises an error saying that the function should be `DETERMINISTIC`.

I did a trick! I've added the function `DETERMINISTIC` keyword (although it's not) and then created the materialized view successfully. After then I've removed the `DETERMINISTIC` keyword from the function and the materialized view works.

Is it OK to have a non-deterministic function within a virtual column and use that virtual column in a materialized view with fast refresh? Is the materialized view still fast refresh?

Comment: Try refreshing it once :)

Comment: @San I've recompiled it and refreshed it, and it works!

Comment: Did you refresh after you updated or inserted into any base table? If not, then the refresh does not do anything.

Comment: @Wernfried Yes I've updated some rows (those one involved in the non-deterministic function) And the materialized view is updated correctly! Unfortunately!

Comment: Fine, then go for it. I assume when you create an index on this column and then alter the function then such index becomes "unusable".

Comment: try EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW ('my_mat_view').  Then look in MV_CAPABILITIES_TABLE.

Comment: @Wernfried yep, seems so. I haven't declared any index on it.

Comment: @tbone Thanks for your great hint. I've checked it and it says: For 'REFRESH_FAST', 'POSSIBLE=NO'. It really helps to understand the materialized view. Why don't you post it as an answer!?

Comment: Then you should check view `ALL_MVIEWS`if your refresh was successfull and `FAST` or `COMPLETE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using non-deterministic functions in tables or materialized view is not strictly forbidden, as you've already figured out.  The point of the error `ORA-30553: The function is not deterministic` is to ensure you never create a data structure that can be changed without Oracle's knowledge.  If Oracle cannot track changes to tables then many things can break, such as indexes and integrity constraints.

The example below shows a changing function leading to wrong results.  Re-creating a deterministic function to return a different result violates the spirit of `deterministic`.

I believe this also partly answers your previous question, "When does a deterministic function use the previous calculated value?"  It implicitly uses the value all the time when it does not re-validate a constraint or update an index.

```
--#1: Simple deterministic function that returns 1. 
create or replace function not_deterministic return varchar2 deterministic is
begin
    return 'old value';
end;
/

--#2: Virtual table that uses the function and has an index on the function.
drop table deterministic_test;
create table deterministic_test(a char(100), b as (not_deterministic()) not null);
insert into deterministic_test(a) select 1 from dual connect by level <= 100000;
create index deterministic_test_index on deterministic_test(b);
begin
    dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(user, 'deterministic_test');
end;
/

--#3: All the values are 'old value'.
select distinct b from deterministic_test where a is not null;

b
-
old value

--#4: Change the function to return 'new value'.
create or replace function not_deterministic return varchar2 deterministic is
begin
    return 'new value';
end;
/

--#5: Indexes are not maintained leading to wrong, inconsistent results.
--Both should return 'new value'.
select distinct b from deterministic_test;

B
-
old value

select /*+full(deterministic_test)*/ distinct b from deterministic_test;

B
-
new value
```

Comment: Thanks. As a matter of fact I was looking for a sample to show the problems of defining a non-deterministic function as deterministic too. And your answer is surely one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to create a virtual column in a materialized view, this contradicts the purpose of materialized views.

A materialized view is used to **store** values where it would take too much time to calculate or select them. Thus values comming from virtual columns should be stored also.

Comment: I'm not creating virtual column in the materialized view, I'm using a already defined virtual column from a table.